# git remove directory with special char ( symbol) in it

Tags: git

I got this directories:

- main%F0java
- main%F0res

created for any reason (I guess android studio is to blame) and committed it on a rush. the fact is thath %F0 is the  symbol so when I go to commit/remove via terminal/source tree I always fail.

I tried:

```
git rm -rf *java
```

but got

```
fatal: pathspec 'main%F0java' did not match any files
```

I just started to pull out my (few) hair. Anyway around this mess ? I'm on a mac btw

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808611/git-checkout-remove-file-with-special-characters

Comment: Try deleting them in terminal `rm -rf *java` then commit changes using git

Comment: woa! never tryed via console. IT JUST WORKS!! thanks Issam

Answer (score 0):

removing and committing via the console (not with sourcetree) seemed to work. thanks to Issam